# HTML Agility Pack Select Nodes with Multiple Attributes

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

This might be a simple and stupid question but I can't seem to find anything on selecting a node that has multiple attribute.  In my case it is a specific class and a specific style.

Here is a snippet from the HTML I am working with.

```
<div class="buying" style="padding-bottom: 0.75em;">
<span class="availGreen">Blah Blah</span><br /> Blah Blah Blah<b>Sold By</b>.
</div>
```

There are many different instances of the class "buying" but only one instance of the div that includes both the buying class and the style="padding-bottom: 0.75em attributes.  I am trying to grab the text inside the  tag.

Here is what I have tried but I got nowhere:

```
SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='buying'][@style='padding-bottom: 0.75em;']/b").InnerText;
```

And also:

```
SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='buying' @style='padding-bottom: 0.75em;']/b").InnerText;
```

Neither of these produced any results but I am not sure what else is correct.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try joining them with [`and`](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp) (I believe that's the correct XPath way of selecting multiple attributes):

```
SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='buying' and @style='padding-bottom: 0.75em;']/b").InnerText;
```

Comment: Thanks!  Knew it had to be simple.

Comment: what if value is wild card means ,how to find with class and style with any value..