# Select multiple paths/tags in HTML Agility Pack SelectNodes

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I want to extract all HTML code snippets which are between either the `<h1> </h1>` tags or the `<h2> </h2>` tags. I can't use `SelectNodes(".//h1")` and `SelectNodes(".//h2")` separately because I also need to preserve the order between them.

I looked for any existing answers on SO, but I could only find answers to how to deal with [multiple attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15044402/16424700), but couldn't find how to deal with multiple HTML tags.

Answer (score 1):

I found that multiple tags can be combined using `|` (the [union](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/#prod-xpath31-UnionExpr) operator).

So using `SelectNodes(".//h1 | .//h2")` worked for me, and it returned the nodes corresponding to both tags.